# Radio button with search box for HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I have jQuery and table shown below:

```js
console.clear();

function inputSelected(val) {
    $("#result").html(function() {
        var str = '';
        $(":checked").each(function() {
            str += $(this).val() + " ";
        });
        if (val == 1) {
            return $('#testSearch').val();
        }
        str += $('#testSearch').val();
        return str;
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=radio]").click(inputSelected);

    $("td.other").click(function() {
        $(this).find('input[type=text]').focus();
    });

    $('#testSearch').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
        inputSelected(1);
    })

    $("td.other input[type=text]").keyup(function(e) {
        var value = $(this).val().trim();

        if (value.length <= 0) {
            value = 'Other';
        }

        $(this).parent().siblings("input[type=radio]").val(value);
        $(this).parent().siblings("label").html(value);

        inputSelected();

    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="test" type="radio" value="You enter A" id="1" />A</td>
    <td class="other"><input name="test" type="radio" value=""  id="2"/>Other:
      <div class="text">
        <input type="text" id="other" value="">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td><input name="test" type="radio" value=""  id="3"/>Search<input id='testSearch' type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="result">
 </div>
```

In this table I have 3 radio buttons:

1. Simple Radio Button
2. Radio Button with input box
3. Radio Button with search box

Like first 2 radio buttons 3rd 'search box' button is not working. For example when I click radio button 'a', it display "You enter A" then I click radio button 'other' and enter some text, on result it hide my last selected button display and show me whatever I type. Same if I select 'search' radio button it hide last selected button display and show me whatever I type.

But

After entering something to search when I clicked on any other 2 radio button, it did not hide text that I insert to search.

So, my problem is that when I select any one radio button, it should hide previous selected output like radio button 'A' and 'other' do.

Kindly advise me what changes I have to make in this script for such purpose. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch.
Also I commented some of Your code.

```js
function inputSelected(val) {
    $("#result").html(function() {
        if (val == 1) {
            return $('#testSearch').val();
        }
        var str = '';
        $(":checked").each(function() {
            str += $(this).val() + " ";
        });
        //str += $('#testSearch').val();
        return str;
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name=test]").click(inputSelected);

    $("td.other").click(function() {
        $(this).find('input[type=text]').focus();
    });

    $('#testSearch').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
        $("input[class=testSearch]").val($('input[id=testSearch]').val());
        if($("input[class=testSearch]").is(':checked')){
            inputSelected(1);
            }
    })

    $("td.other input[type=text]").keyup(function(e) {
        var value = $(this).val().trim();

        if (value.length <= 0) {
            value = 'Other';
        }

        $(this).parent().siblings("input[type=radio]").val(value);
        $(this).parent().siblings("label").html(value);

        inputSelected();

    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="test" type="radio" value="You enter A" id="1"/>A</td>
    <td class="other"><input name="test" type="radio" value="" id="2"/>Other:
      <div class="text">
        <input type="text" id="other" value="">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td><input name="test" class="testSearch" type="radio" value=""  id="3"/>Search<input id='testSearch' type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="result"></div>
```